# How to revert Angular 2 update

Tags: angular

I just updated my angular 2 application by running npm update and unfortunately my app doesn't run anymore although no errors are showing in the terminal, there are lot of errors in my console. Is there anyway i could reverse the update?

//error

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:4200/app/assets/js/jquery.min.js was not loaded because its MIME type, “application/javascript”, is not “text/css”. localhost:4200
GET 
http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/systemjs.config.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8ms]
ReferenceError: System is not defined[Learn More]  localhost:4200:29:5
TypeError: f is undefined[Learn More]  scripts.bundle.js%20line%2034%20%3E%20eval:15:3
Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css undefined  vendor.bundle.js:129451:13
Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber: Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack: Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString: createMethodProperty/props[key].value(), 5 more… }  vendor.bundle.js:129453:9
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
    "angular-2-data-table": "^0.1.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^0.2.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.25",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.1",
    "primeng": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "tinymce": "^4.5.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.0-beta.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use any version control? npm has no integrated history of what your package.json looked like.

Comment: `git reset --hard master`? Seriously, if you're not using a version control system, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Just try fixing the errors instead of reverting back. How ever one fine day you need to update them!

Comment: @JBNizet yeah  i pushed my files into gitlab account some days back

Comment: "lot of errors in my console" such as? Post some of it so we can see.

Comment: @BenDadsetan Yeah i do..

Comment: @msanford i have updated the error. the error seems to be from my index.html

Comment: @Switz What makes you think that? If it's because that's where the errors are being emitted, that's normal, it's probably where you're bootstrapping your app.

Comment: @msanford  what could be wrong with where i am bootstrapping my app?

Comment: @Switz Sure, post that, too. And maybe post your package.json as well. I offered a quick workaround for now that might help. Ben's suggestion is applicable if you changed your package.json file, mine is if you did not change it.

Comment: Am not sure the OP is aware the OP updated the package.json indirectly with the npm update.

Comment: @msanford i just run nom upgrade but i don't know if it tempered with the package.json. i was basically following a tutorial and i had to upgrade. the package.json file is up

Comment: `npm update` does not touch the `package.json`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Delete your **node_modules** directory
2. restore your previous **package.json** file from your version
   control system
3. run **npm install**

You also delete and recreate your **dist** or generated files folder and rebuild.

Edit: You can attempt to update your packages the way @msanford but be aware sometimes it will still upgrade to incompatible versions. I always try to use well maintained seed versions of packages known to work well together. Specially for zonejs.

Comment: I can't see another reason for a problem after npm update.

Comment: perhaps his packages are wildly out of date but the ^/~ specifiers allowed a more recent version to be installed that is no longer compatible with his architecture/dependencies/peers etc.

Comment: The OP asked to revert. That's the instructions I gave. :)
In my experience, angular2 does not depend on packages that perfectly describe their dependencies. There is a number of times where I had to downgrade 3-4 packages after doing a major update.

Comment: Indeed, your suggestion is logical. I was reading between the lines. And depending on the version of angular OP is running, it might cross a deprecation boundary (happened to us) unwittingly. You deserve a +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

If you believe an update to your installed node modules is to blame, and you have *not modified* your `package.json` go into your package.json and (temporarily) remove the `^` and `~` before version numbers; try `npm install` again.

This will direct npm to install the exact patch version specified, and will not attempt to upgrade it to the latest patch (`~`) or latest minor (`^`) verison.

When you ran `npm update`, that told npm to go get the latest versions of each of the packages you specified, *up to the latest patch/minor allowed*, as indicated by the ~ or ^. You may have introduced an incompatibility this way.

Ben's suggestion is appropriate if you changed your `package.json` file, so if you did, try his suggestion.

Comment: i have to remove it from everyline?

Comment: @Switz I'm doubting myself now, since you're running angular 2.4.8 which is pretty recent... It's just a debugging step. Try it. Find and replace. This is of course assuming you _haven't modified_ your package file, in which case this answer will be useless to you.

Comment: I can say the same about your suggestions. +1 from me.